# Is android pentesting partially similar to web pentesting?

Tags: web-application, android, client-side

I'm already into web pentesting. I'm willing to learn android pentesting now.

From what I understand, the server side part like API etc is similar to web pentesting and I need to learn about client side bugs.

Am I correct?

Comment: This question is opinion based. Different organizations may use different objectives and thus different methodology. The methodology that some persons find similar the others will find very different, e.g. some may consider pentesting of *any* applications similar: Android, iOS, normal Web applications, RMI, etc. The others may say that even pentesing of an App for Android 10 is very different from pentesting for Android 4. That's why I suggest to close the question.

Comment: Do all mobile applications use a web API - no. Are things like XSS relevant for mobile application - it depends on the technology these apps exactly use. Are there problems specific to mobile apps which are not relevant for web apps - yes. Are there problems specific to web apps which are not relevant for mobile apps - yes. Is there some overlap in problems - yes. Does this overlap count as "similar" - depends on the amount of overlap in your specific case and what you see as similar. Is red similar to blue - kind of, both a colors and both are in the visible spectrum.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I'm willing to get into android pentesting so in my case understanding the overlap will give me an idea about the learning curve. My assumption is the server side part must be similar as web and client part is different.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the application(s) that you end up reviewing, but typically in terms of skillset, for Android mobile applications there's a couple of areas to cover in addition to web API knowledge.

1. Knowledge of the Android ecosystem. How the operating system works, and what good practice and common issues look like. So things like how should secrets be stored on the client device, permissions that applications can/should request.
2. Often pentesting an Android application would be best done in a white-box fashion, so being able to read and understand the language(s) commonly used to create android applications and common application frameworks is likely to be helpful.

Server-side (where the application is communicating with a remote server) then yes these are often (but not always) REST APIs, so knowing that + common supporting technologies (e.g. OAuth) is likely to be valuable.